# How to properly use a php page displayed on form action

Tags: php

I've got a finished site already and I'm working on the customer callback form where they put in name, email, tel for me to contact them. The way I have it now is that on form action I specify "php/sendform.php" scrip. In that script I put all the html that my normal web pages have like footer and header with a message Thank you for contacting us. Everything works but it seems a little awkward and I've never seen this on other mainstream sites, where all of a sudden the address bar changes to a php page where all the other pages on site are html.

So my question is, is there a way to maybe call the php in an async way? Or somehow mask the address bar where it doesn't reveal the php directory because now it just says site.com/php/sendform.php. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK Most modern websites utilize JavaScript and AJAX to send form data

Comment: Either that or they process the data and render a different (HTML) page server side and send that back to the client's browser

Comment: What's wrong with redirecting upon successfully sending mail?

Comment: @UnholySheep I will look into it, you don't happen to have a good explanation on how to do it with AJAX?

Comment: Just googling "JavaScript AJAX" yields some tutorials (e.g.: on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)), although you might consider using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) which simplifies it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL rewriting. Change your form action to `submit`. And in your .htaccess file add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^submit?$    php/sendform.php    [NC,L]
```

So now your php page will look like this:

**yourdomain.extension/submit**

Comment: Note that this assumes OP is using Apache HTTP server (or compatible), which has not been explicitly specified in the question

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for, and coincidentally I am on apache.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work with GoDaddy. I found this version and it works, but can you help me rewrite it so it works as your example above?

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove php extension from the request by means of a redirect.
    # This should really be for php files that exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L,NC]

    # 1. Map the request to a PHP file, if one exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Why does indenting by 4 spaces not work? Sorry about that.